# Efficient way to join two tables with one to many relationship

Tags: join, interview-question

This is interview question asked to me in interview and i was not able to answer. Please help..

What is the most efficient way to join two table with one to many relationship between them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most effective way is to use an INNER JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM        Parent P
INNER JOIN  Child  C
    ON      C.ParentId = P.ParentId
```

And when you need aggregates on child level, you can add a GROUP BY and SUM and/or AVG or other aggregate functions:

```
SELECT      P.Name
            , P.Address
            , SUM(C.Amount)
FROM        Parent P
INNER JOIN  Child  C
    ON      C.ParentId = P.ParentId
GROUP BY    P.Name
            , P.Address
```

Comment: Thanks ypercube for your perceptiveness, I changed the GROUP BY.

Comment: Depending on the DBMS and the data distribution the most effective way might be to group the child first and then join on the grouped result

Comment: How we can have list of result? 
I mean wanna have result that every item has list of it's one to many relations.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question explicitly states "with a one-to-many relationship",  perhaps they are asking you to explain primary-key and foreign-key relationships.

In this case, you might say:

> The table on the "one" side of the "one-to-many" relationship should have a primary key column.  The other table should have a foreign-key defined pointing to the primary key on the first table.  To return results from both tables you'd add an `INNER JOIN` clause to join both tables.